No captura el nombre de un archivo en un formulario para update
Tengo un formulario con varios campos, uno de ellos es un archivo de img. Cuando intento hacer un update, el controller no recibe el nombre del archivo que se cargó y cuya url está correctamente grabada en el registro.
Este es el campo del formulario:
<div class="col-sm-4">
          <label for="cedula_img" class="form-label">Cédula imagen:</label>
          <input type="file" class="form-control" accept="image/jpeg, image/png" id="cedula_img" name="cedula_img" value="<?= $solicitud['cedula_img']; ?>">
          
          <img src="<?= $solicitud['cedula_img']; ?>" style="max-width: 100px;" alt="">
          <p class="small" style="display: inline-block;"><?= $solicitud['cedula_img']; ?></p>
          
          <p class="small" style="color:red">
            <?= validation_show_error('cedula_img'); ?>
          </p>
        </div>

El input id="cedula_img" es lo que no recoge la url grabada, y cuando intento validar el formulario me da un error diciendo NO FILE WAS UPLOADED y tengo que volver a seleccionar la imagen. Sin embargo, imprimiendo el valor de $solicitud['cedula_img'] se ve correctamente el nombre de la url.
Y este es el controller:
public function update($id = null)
{
    $session = session();
    $reglas = [                     // de validacion
        'afiliado_id'           => 'required',
        'nombre'                => 'required', 
        'apellidos'             => 'required', 
        'cedula'                => 'required', 
        'pasaporte'             => 'required', 
        'licencia'              => 'required', 
        'residencia'            => 'required', 
        'ciudad'                => 'required', 
        'pais'                  => 'required', 
        'whatsapp'              => 'required', 
        'email'                 => 'required', 
        'afiliado'              => 'required', 
        'cargo'                 => 'required', 
        'posicion'              => 'required'
    ];
    if(!$this->validate($reglas)){
        $session->setFlashdata('mensaje', 'Error(s) en formulario');
        return redirect()->back()->withInput()->with('error', $this->validator->listErrors());
    } else {
        $post = $this->request->getPost(['afiliado_id', 'nombre', 'apellidos', 'cedula', 'cedula_img', 'pasaporte', 'licencia', 'residencia', 'ciudad', 'pais', 'whatsapp', 'email', 'afiliado', 'cargo', 'posicion']);
        $file = $this->request->getFile('cedula_img');
        if(!$file->isValid()) {
            echo $file->getErrorString();
            exit;
        };
        if(!$file->hasMoved()) { // si el archivo todavia no se ha movido, se fuerza a moverse a su ubicacion temporal writeable/uploads
            $ruta = ROOTPATH . 'public\img\cedulas' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR; // fija la ruta para guardar/mover en disco a su ubicacion definitiva (public)
            $file->move($ruta, $post['cedula_img'], true); // mueve el fichero de la carpeta temporal a su ubicacion definitiva
            $url = base_url() . 'img/cedulas/' . $file->getName(); // consigue la url para guardarla en el registro y verla en html
        };
        $data = [
            'afiliado_id'           => $post['afiliado_id'],
            'nombre'                => $post['nombre'],
            'apellidos'             => $post['apellidos'],
            'cedula'                => $post['cedula'],
            'cedula_img'            => $url,
            'pasaporte'             => $post['pasaporte'],
            'licencia'              => $post['licencia'],
            'residencia'            => $post['residencia'],
            'ciudad'                => $post['ciudad'],
            'pais'                  => $post['pais'],
            'whatsapp'              => $post['whatsapp'],
            'email'                 => $post['email'],
            'afiliado'              => $post['afiliado'],
            'cargo'                 => $post['cargo'],
            'posicion'              => $post['posicion']
        ];
        $this->solicitudesModel->update($id, $data, false);
        $session->setFlashdata('mensaje', 'Solicitud actualizada');
        return redirect('solicitudes');
    }
}

El proceso es bien sencillo pero algo se me pasa. Se agradece ayuda.
